# AWS EKS WITH FARGATE PROFILE USING KONG INGRESS- Unable to expose port 80 to public

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-fargate, amazon-eks, kong-ingress

I deployed kong ingress controller on aws eks cluster with fargate option.
I am unable to access out application over the internet over http port.
I am keep getting -ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT in browser.

I did follow the Kong deployment as per steps given at -
https://github.com/Kong/kubernetes-ingress-controller/blob/master/docs/deployment/eks.md

Kong-proxy service is created wihtout issue.
kong-proxy service is created yet its “EXTERNAL-IP” is still showing pending.
[image]

We are able to access our local application in internal network (by logging on to running pod) via Kong-proxy CLUSTER-IP without any problem using curl.

A nlb load balancer is also created automatically in aws console when we created kong-proxy service. Its DNS name we are using to try to connect from internet.

Kindly help me understand what could be the problem.
My kong-proxy yaml is-

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol: http
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: nlb
  name: kong-proxy
  namespace: kong
spec:
  externalTrafficPolicy: Local
  ports:
  - name: proxy
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 80
  - name: proxy-ssl
    port: 443
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 443
  selector:
    app: ingress-kong
  type: LoadBalancer
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's supported now as per https://github.com/aws/containers-roadmap/issues/617